# Solr - Is the "maxWriteMBPerSec" config value in megabytes or megabits?

Tags: solr, config

The documentation doesn't define whether the "maxWriteMBPerSec" uses megabytes, or megabits. I presume it's bytes and bits would be small, but could someone please confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in megabytes. From [the Lucene source code for RateLimiter.SimpleRateLimiter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/store/RateLimiter.java#L107):

```
double secondsToPause = (bytes/1024./1024.) / mbPerSec;
```